# Unable to apply class while creating element

Tags: javascript

In the first example, when I append text `helloWorldPara1.textContent += 'world';` the class `('red')` applied above, to `hello.classList.add('red')` doesn't apply. If I comment out `helloWorldPara1.textContent += 'world';` I get hello in red.

In the second example, it seems to work as I applied the class last.

Why can't I append an element with a class then append extra text?

```
.red{
    color: red;
}
```

```
<div id="helloWorld1"></div>
<div id="helloWorld2"></div>
```

```
// 1. Hello world html div
const helloWorld1 = document.getElementById('helloWorld1');

// Create p
const helloWorldPara1 = document.createElement("p");
// span - hello
const hello = document.createElement("span");
hello.classList.add('red')
hello.textContent = 'hello ';
// Append to Para
helloWorldPara1.appendChild(hello);
// Append text
helloWorldPara1.textContent += 'world'; // Commenting out applies class red to "hello"
// Append p to html div
helloWorld1.appendChild(helloWorldPara1);

// 2. Hello world html div
const helloWorld2 = document.getElementById('helloWorld2');

// Create p
const helloWorldPara2 = document.createElement("p");
// Append text
helloWorldPara2.textContent += 'hello ';
// span - world
const world = document.createElement("span");
world.classList.add('red')
world.textContent = 'world';
// Append to Para
helloWorldPara2.appendChild(world);
// Append p to html div
helloWorld2.appendChild(helloWorldPara2);
```

Comment: Because `textContent += ...` overwrites the whole content of the element. This needs to _read_ the current text content of the element first, and the element's text does not contain any span to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at what is going on.

### The problem

At this point

```
helloWorldPara1.appendChild(hello);
```

we have this HTML:

```
<p><span class="red">hello </span></p>
    ^^^^                    ^^^^^
span being a readily parsed HTML element.
```

Now if you read the `textContent` of this `<p>`, you will get

```
"hello "
```

That is because `textContent`, as the name is trying to convey, **does only read text**, *not elements*.

When you write to the textContent property of an element, you will effectively delete whatever is between the opening tag and the closing tag, and replace it with whatever you're assigning.

So by doing

```
helloWorldPara1.textContent += 'world';
```

You are replacing

```
<span class="red">hello </span>
```

by

```
'hello ' + 'world'
```

and thus removing your `<span class="red">` in the process.

### How to fix

The simplest fix is to work with `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`, which reads and writes HTML tags as well as the textual content.

This would be a bad solution for security and performance reasons, so the best way is to create the text you want to append just like you created the `p` and  the `span`, with the help of `document.createTextNode()`:

```js
// 1. Hello world html div
const helloWorld1 = document.getElementById('helloWorld1');

// Create p
const helloWorldPara1 = document.createElement("p");
// span - hello
const hello = document.createElement("span");
hello.classList.add('red')
hello.textContent = 'hello ';
// Append to Para
helloWorldPara1.appendChild(hello);
// Append text
helloWorldPara1.appendChild(document.createTextNode('world'))
// Append p to html div
helloWorld1.appendChild(helloWorldPara1);
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="helloWorld1"></div>
<div id="helloWorld2"></div>
```